How to narrow the return type within a function based on the value of an argument?
Im trying to combine the methods of an interface into a single function with an additional operation parameter. The resulting function can be called as expected, but it seems I can't get the return type to narrow within the function.
The answer to an earlier question of mine was helpful regarding the narrowing of parameter types, but the narrowing of the return type within the function is still a mystery to me:
interface Machine {
    doSomething: (arg: number) => string;
    doSomethingElse: (args: boolean) => number;
};

type MachineParameters = {
    [K in keyof Machine]: [K, ...Parameters<Machine[K]>];
}[keyof Machine];

const execute = <T extends MachineParameters>(...args: T): ReturnType<Machine[T[0]]> => {
    switch (args[0]) {
        case "doSomething":
            // Error: Type '`${number}`' is not assignable to type 'MachineReturnTypes[T[0]]'.
            return `${args[1]}`;
        case "doSomethingElse":
            // Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'MachineReturnTypes[T[0]]'.
            return Number(args[1]);
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown operation");
    }
};

// Works: string
const x = execute("doSomething", 1);
// Works: number
const y = execute("doSomethingElse", true);

Playground

The trick I like to use to narrow the arguments of possible multiple overloads inside of the function is to declare the implementation arguments as a union of tuples of the overloads. It's a little bit repetitive, but TS is very good in narrowing tuples, by member type or by size.
// overloads
function execute(operation: 'doSomething', arg: number): string;
function execute(operation: 'doSomethingElse', arg: boolean): number;
// implementation
function execute(
    ...args: [operation: 'doSomething', arg: number] | [operation: 'doSomethingElse', arg: boolean]
): string | number {
    switch (args[0]) {
        case "doSomething":
            // args is narrowed to [operation: 'doSomething', arg: number]
            return `${args[1]}`;
        case "doSomethingElse": 
            // args is narrowed to [operation: 'doSomethingElse', arg: boolean]
            return Number(args[1]);
        default:
            // args is narrowed to never
            throw new Error(`Unknown operation ${args[0]}`);
    }
};


Playground

You can use function overloads to specify return types based on the operation parameter:
interface Machine {
  ...
}

function execute(operation: 'doSomething', arg: number): string;
function execute(operation: 'doSomethingElse', arg: boolean): number;
function execute(operation: keyof Machine, args: any): any {
  ...
}

See playground
